# Installing zmq gem on Mountain Lion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, homebrew, zeromq

Installed zmq via homebrew.

Then tried to run:

```
$ sudo gem install zmq -- --with-zmq-dir=/usr/local
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing zmq:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb --with-zmq-dir=/usr/local
checking for zmq.h... yes
checking for zmq_init() in -lzmq... no
checking for zmq_init() in -lzmq... no
extconf.rb:36: Couldn't find zmq library. try setting --with-zmq-dir=<path> to tell me where it is. (RuntimeError)


Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/zmq-2.1.4 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/zmq-2.1.4/gem_make.out
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What's brew doctor say?

Comment: Also did you try: ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install zmq -- --with-zmq-dir=/usr/local

Comment: I don't think the zmq gem is actually compatible with current zeromq.  I think you need to use `ffi-rzmq` for libzmq >= 3.0.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that [the current gem does not work with 3.x.x](https://github.com/zeromq/rbzmq/issues/25).
You can however install ZeroMQ 2.2.0 with `brew install zeromq22`, the gem will install just fine after that.

Answer (score 2):

Without the ZeroMQ system library, the `zmq` gem has no hope of compiling. If you're using Homebrew, this is an easy process, though:

```
brew install zeromq
```

If you've already done this but it can't be found, it's possible your compiler is not finding the ZeroMQ library. You'll want to look for it with `find /usr -name 'libzmq*'` and see where it's hiding. It might be in another directory than `/usr/local/lib`.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ brew install zeromq22
$ gem install zmq -- --with-zmq-dir=/usr/local/opt/zeromq22
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `--with-zmq-dir=/usr/local`, try also adding `--with-zmq-lib=/usr/local/lib` and `--with-zmq-include=/usr/local/include` to your gem install command. Normally just --with-zmq-dir should suffice, but that doesn't seem to be the case with this gem.